# How to add a table to a silverlight richtextbox?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have used  [Silverlight RichTextEditor](https://richtexteditor.codeplex.com/)  for my project.
Here there is no provision for adding a table. Is there any other method to do so?

Answer (score 0):

[VectorLight](http://www.vectorlight.net/silverlight/demos/richtextbox.aspx) has a Free Richtextbox. It has almost every text editing controls including table insertion. So you can use this in your project.

Comment: thanks,I am able to insert table using VectorLight's Free RichTextBox but now the problem is that i am not able to save it as xml. is there any method to do so. Earlier i was using Rich Text Editor https://richtexteditor.codeplex.com/ where which i could easily save as xml.

Comment: Can you show the code which you are using for XML serialization? Or add this as a new question in SO with your code.